# How to calculate WMA(weighted moving average) and Hull MA for AAPL in anystock/anychart?

Tags: javascript, anychart

I need to calculate WMA(weighted moving average) and Hull MA for AAPL in anychart. Please let me know any built in functions are available in Anystock/Anychart

Answer (score 0):

The AnyChart library doesn't include these indicators, but both can be implemented as custom indicators using the library API.
WMA logic was already used in [a custom Coppock indicator](https://playground.anychart.com/I0dyA2CO).
Also, you can check other custom indicators in [the blog](https://www.anychart.com/blog/tag/custom-technical-indicators/).
In [the documentation article](https://docs.anychart.com/Stock_Charts/Technical_Indicators/Custom_Indicators), you can check the API description required for building custom indicators.